# Add function to dynamic button in C#

Tags: c#, forms, function, events, button

I dynamically created a Form and inside I created a button, but when I try to add my function to the button it gives this error:

> Method name expected.

I am using the following code:

```
        {
        ...
        Form newForm = new Form();
        newform.Size = new Size(477, 222);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Size = new Size(121, 23);
        btn.Location = new Point(231, 102);
        btn.Text = "Text";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Funct(label1.Text, label12.Text));
        newForm.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    public void Funct(string stringA, string stringB)
    {
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(path);
        write.WriteLine(stringA + "-" + stringB);
        write.Close();
    }
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda, change click event to

```
btn.Click += (s, e) => { Funct(label1.Text, label12.Text) };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the Funct does not comply with the signature for the Click event:

Try:

public void Funct(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
...
}

If you want to dynamically pass the strings, you may have to create your own EventArgs class adding the additional properties there.

Hope that helps.